# Change Spring Boot dependency to 3.2.0-RC1

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

My app depends on Spring Boot v3.1.5 and is built with Gradle. I want to update to the release candidate for v3.2.0, so I made the following change in `build.gradle

```
plugins {

    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0-RC1' // was 3.1.5
}
```

In the same file I have declared the following repositories should be used to resolve dependencies

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}
```

When I try to build/run the app I get the following error

> Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '3.2.0-RC1'] was not
> found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.0-RC1')
>   Searched in the following repositories:
>   Gradle Central Plugin Repository

If I navigate to the milestone repository in a browser, I can see that [version 3.2.0-RC1 of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin exists](https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/3.2.0-RC1/), so I don't know why it's failing to resovle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding that milestone repo to the `repositories` block in `build.gradle` tells Gradle where to find the milestone Spring Boot jar files during the build. You also need to tell the build system where to find the Spring Boot plugin jars. You can do that by adding this to your `settings.gradle` file.

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks!